# How can I prevent form submission if value is too short?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent any form submission, if the input field is not at least 3 chars long. My button is disabled if length <= 3 but I cant prevent the submission on "Enter".

```
 <form name="form" action="..." method="POST" id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Add" disabled>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('#form');
    const inputName = document.querySelector('#name');
    const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('#btnSubmit');

    inputName.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        btnSubmit.disabled = inputName.value.length < 3;
    });

    inputName.addEventListener('keypress', function (event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (inputName.value.length >= 3) form.submit();
        }
    });

    form.addEventListener('keypress', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Seems I used it wrong in the first try. Thx

Comment: U realize that someone can still manually send the form. They don't have to use your form to create the url that is sent to your server. Just saying...

Comment: You have to reject the form on the backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

Modify last part of your script as below:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a minlength value for your input field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  minlength="3" required>
```

The minlength attribute defines the minimum number of characters (as UTF-16 code units) the user can enter into an  or . This must be an integer value 0 or higher.
The input will fail constraint validation if the length of the text value of the field is less than minlength UTF-16 code units long, with validityState.tooShort returning true. Constraint validation is only applied when the value is changed by the user. Once submission fails, some browsers will display an error message indicating the minimum length required and the current length.

Source: [HTML attribute: minlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength)

Comment: That doesn't prevent someone from manually querying the entry via a URL in the address bar, or a `$ curl ...` command from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Set a minlength value for your input field

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input minlength attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" minlength="8"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image of running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncsTJ.png)